# restrict access to specific attributes openldap proxy

Tags: centos, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, proxy, openldap

I try to config OpendLdap in proxy mode of Active Directory to browse specific attributes and not all.

When I browse my AD with ldapsearch, it works, but it displayed all of attributes, I just want attributes as:

```
sn,givenName,streetAddress,l,postaCode,mail,telephoneNumber,mobile.
```

I've create an access rule on this specific attributes for a specific user, but it don't works

see my rule :

```
access to dn.subtree="ou=xxxx,dc=xxxx,dc=fr" attrs="entry,sn,givenName,
    streetAddress,l,postaCode,mail,telephoneNumber,mobile"
    by dn="cn=xxxxxx,OU=xxxxx,dc=xxx,dc=fr" read
    by * none
```

What did I forget?

Comment: With your acl do you still receive all attributes or none of them? Which user is: cn=xxxxxx,OU=xxxxx,dc=xxx,dc=fr ?

Comment: My problem is solved, my slapd.conf was not applyed because my folder slapd.d wasn't empty. I just remove everything into this one and my access rules works better.